August 2024 Photo Contest: Birds
The topic is "birds", so photos containing at least one bird (no maximum).
The contest will end at the end of August (UTC time). The following rules apply:

Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
You can make up to three posts (attempts).
Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
Keep it nice, CoC-compliant, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
If you have people recognizable in the photo, you must either (a) have their permission to post the photo or (b) make them unrecognizable.
If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
The photo may have been taken any time.
If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the list of possible photo competition topics.
Also, you can join us in chat to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.


Goofy blue-footed boobies
Isla de Plata, Ecuador
March 2019


This post had the most upvotes at the end of the month - congratulations!


I took this photo of a puffin in Iceland in July 2024!




Harris's hawk in Oberreith, Germany, April 23rd, 2022


A few chinstrap penguins in the foreground; thousands more in the background. Taken by me at Baily Head on Deception Island, February 23, 2019.

Indian Eagle Owl
Photographed in Gurugram, Haryana, India in May 2024
They are large owls and live in rocky areas.


Congratulations on winning the virtual prize this month!

Thanks you @cocomac

Blue-and-yellow macaw
Pantanal, Brazil
February 2023


I waited for hours for the seagull to show up and...no it was totally by chance of course!! Own picture taken in July 2020 from Ponte dell'Accademia in Venice, Italy.



Seagulls in Moskenes, Norway, July 21st, 2007


Common kestrel (I assume), Neusiedler See, Austria, April 19th, 2022


Flamingos are so awkward on the ground, but not in the air. Taken by me at the Laguna Chulluncani in Southwestern Bolivia, on February 9, 2019.

These two ducks posing for me in Chợ Nguyễn Công Trứ market in Hanoi, Vietnam, in November 2023. I took this photo with my Samsung A50 phone.


That's me with an eagle standing on my arm.

This was taken by my wife in June/2015, in Maca, Peru.

Right after that, we went to Mirador Cruz del Cóndor, where we could see the condors flying:



A chaffinch taking my crumbs at a tea garden in UK in June 2006.
It's in reasonable focus but the bird's body might not be still.



I took the photo of this duck today 9 August 2024, in the Zuiderzeemuseum Enkhuizen, the Netherlands.

Someone forgot the no downvotes rule.


Here is a fine European eagle specimen demonstrating how bird watching goes both ways. The photo was taken at the Falconhof in Schmitten, Germany in early February 2024. Despite the signage, this raptor looked and acted like the real thing, even at such close range. The craftsmanship is remarkable!

German speakers, who are warned to keep back because the birds might bite, are entertained by the English speakers that think the birds are fake.
